# delete item that only has no edit rights

Tags: permissions, item, delete, unique

I made a workflow that (among other things) changes the rights of an item. It changed that a certain group only had read rights instead of edit rights. I, as an admin, am also in that group unfortunately. I didn't specify the rights of another group.

Now nobody is able to delete the item.

How do I delete this item? I can't start a workflow either...

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are the Site Collection Administrator of the site you should be able to delete the items, else contact the Site Collection Administrator to perform it.